# Print each value in list "n" times

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner and I am trying to solve this [code](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fp-list-replication). Given n and a List,  return a new list containing all the elements of list repeated n times. 
Below is my implementation

```
fn :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
replicate' n x = take n (repeat x)
fn n (x:xs) = case x of [] -> []
                        (_) ->  (replicate' n x) ++ fn n xs
```

But I am getting error saying

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `[t0]'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for fn :: Int -> [a] -> [a] at temp.hs:3:1
In the pattern: []
In a case alternative: [] -> []
In the expression:
  case x of {
    [] -> []
    (_) -> (replicate' n x) ++ fn n xs }
```

I am not sure where the error is. 
Note: I am not attempting monad, any library. I am using only basic constructs
Edit: I am not worried about printing as of now. I want to return the list as specified in the logic. Print can be taken care later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the pattern `fn n (x:xs) = ...` that means `x` is the first element in the list and `xs` is the rest of the list. Your case statement is checking whether or not `x` is an empty list, but the pattern match (`(x:xs)`) already extracted it from the list. What you want is probably one of these (the compiler knows they are the same so which one you use is a matter of taste):

```
-- Version that uses a pattern match
fn :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
replicate' n x = take n (repeat x)
fn _ [] = []
fn n (x:xs) = (replicate' n x) ++ fn n xs

-- Version that uses a case statement
fn :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
replicate' n x = take n (repeat x)
fn n l = case l of [] -> []
                   (x:xs) ->  (replicate' n x) ++ fn n xs
```

This one also "fixes the error", but is probably not what you actually want:

```
fn :: Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
replicate' n x = take n (repeat x)
fn n (x:xs) = case x of [] -> []
                        (_) ->  (replicate' n x) ++ fn n xs
```

Answer (score 3):

Jeremy List's explanation directly addresses the OP's question. However, sometimes structured recursion provides a more elegant solution to problems. In this case, for example, this one liner does exactly what the OP asks:

```
fn :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
fn n = concat . map (replicate n)
```

In sum, *map* lifts *replicate* to operate in values of the list, and *concat* concatenates the resulting list of lists.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Using `concatMap` here would be a minor stylistic improvement, IMHO.

Comment: @LuisCasillas absolutely right, concatMap would be a bit better! Anyway, I thought that a composition of independent concat and map would be easier to understand, since the OP says that basic constructs are preferred.

Comment: <interactive>:27:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show ([a0] -> [a0]))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Answer (score 1):

Using do notation

```
replicate' n xs = do
      x  <- xs
      replicate n x
```

which can be written as

```
replicate' n xs = xs >>= replicate n
```

or

```
replicate' n = (>>= replicate n)
```

Comment: great answer! reveals how list is a monad

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution with nested list comprehension.

```
f n arr =
    [ x | x <- arr, _ <- [1..n]]
```